# Class specialization involving CRTP and inner type

Tags: c++, template-specialization, crtp, c++98

I would like to build the following classes. Base class is defining functions to be implemented, Derived implements this interface.

```
template <class T, class V>
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void foo(const typename V::t_args&) =0;
};

template<class T>
struct T_args
{
    T z;
};

class Derived : public IBase<double, Derived>
{
public:
    typedef T_args<double> t_args;

    Derived() {}

    void foo(const t_args& x)
    { /* do some stuff */ }
};
```

Compiler is complaining about Derived as an imcomplete type; I can't understand the reason why.
Is there any mean to get this class structure right?

I'm forced to code with c++98, but I'm interested for any solution in c++11 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your base template class:

```
virtual void foo(const typename V::t_args&) =0;
```

This is referencing some inner class or type called `t_args` of its `V` template parameter. When referencing a class member, the class's definition must be complete (in order to figure out what `t_args` is). You are attempting to use this template class as follows:

```
class Derived : public IBase<double, Derived>
```

You're passing in `Derived` for your `V`, however its class definition is incomplete. If the template base class only referenced its `V` parameter, it is generally "ok". However your template requires its template parameter type to be complete, because it needs to know what the heck that `t_args` is, and your derived class is not complete until it's fully defined. But it cannot be fully defined until its base class is fully defined. Sort of like a chicken vs egg situation.

There is no turnkey solution to this kind of a circular reference, of sorts. The only thing that can be done is restructure the class, so your "argument" type is an independent class, rather than the derived class.

Comment: Quite clear explanation. It makes me realize that the only mean I have is to put the `t_args` class in template of class `Base`, like the class `reverse_iterator` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use some traits class:

```
// The traits class
template <typename T> struct Arg;

template <class T, class V>
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase() {}
    virtual void foo(const typename Arg<V>::t_args&) = 0; // V can be incomplete here
                                                          // but Arg<V> should be complete
};

// So go to define Arg<Derived>:
// Result class
template<class T>
struct T_args
{
    T z;
};

// Forward declaration, Arg<V> accept incomplete type
class Derived;

// Specialization for Derived
// should not use internal of Derived as it is incomplete
template <>
struct Arg<Derived>
{
    typedef T_args<double> t_args;
};

// Now definition of Derived
class Derived : public IBase<double, Derived>
{
public:
    typedef Arg<Derived>::t_args t_args; // Should probably go in IBase for ease usage

    Derived() {}

    void foo(const t_args& x) /* override */
    { /* do some stuff */ }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a31100317cc05bde)

Comment: In my code, after writing down my answer, I ended in doing exactly your solution. I think it's the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [explanation by Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51210522/1507014), here is a potential workaround of my problem by adding the `t_args` class in the template signature of the base class:

```
template <class V, class Args>
class IBase
{
public:
    typedef Args t_args;

    virtual void foo(const Args&) =0;
};

template<class T>
struct T_args
{
    T z;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public IBase<Derived<T>, T_args<T> >
{
public:
    typedef typename Derived::IBase::t_args t_args;

    Derived() {}

    void foo(const t_args&)
    { /* do some stuff */ }
};
```